# generate same data where in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a test table

[image: test_table]

add is count added value for day, and is deleted value for day, diff is defferent add and del fileds plus previous diff

how I can write query and return! see image [image: result image]

where date interval is not one day, there to generate same columns, example 03.05.2018 row is generated row and this is ADD = 0, DEL = 0, AND DIFF = previous 
4, after 11.05.2018 to generate rows to current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate all the rows using `generate_series()`, then `left join`:

```
select 1 as com_id, gs.dte,
       coalesce(add, 0) as add, coalesce(del, 0) as del,
       (sum(add) over (order by gs.dte) -
        sum(del) over (order by gs.dte)
       ) as diff
from generate_series('2018-05-01'::date, current_date, interval '1 day') gs(dte) left join
     test t
     on t.date = gs.dte;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/QQDQ49849) is a rextester.

Comment: this code is not true, returned incorect result, me need as shown on image2

Comment: @AniSevanyan . . . This does work.  I've provided a link to a test.

Comment: image result image [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sRdGTXGJ70CmOc7_KRYL-L5JYTcSLMJ3)

Comment: @AniSevanyan . . . That is not the same data you have in this question.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question with different data.  This one is answered correctly, as shown by the rextester link.  Changing this question is rude, because it would invalidate this answer.